# leaflet.js set duration of fitBounds animation

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I use `Leaflet` to show a map to the user. The map has several markers on it and when the user clicks on one, I want to pan to the marker location and zoom in. I can achieve this by using the following code:

```
    map.fitBounds([
        // bounds of clicked marker
    ]);
```

This works fine and Leaflet even animates the transition. What I would like is set the duration of the animation in miliseconds. `FitBounds` takes some [options](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitboundsoptions), but none of them allows me to specify the duration of the panning and zooming animation. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's incorrect, the fitBounds method does accept the [zoom/pan options](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoompanoptions) of which pan options has duration as stated in the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitboundsoptions) for the fitBounds options.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is [`flyToBounds(<LatLngBounds> bounds, <fitBounds options> options?)`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-flytobounds)

> Sets the view of the map with a smooth animation like [`flyTo`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-flyto), but takes
> a bounds parameter like [`fitBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-fitbounds).

```
map.flyToBounds(bounds, { duration: 1 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

As @leonhees says you can use [flyToBounds](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-flytobounds) to fit leaflet map according to an object (polyline, polygon, etc).

even though you can add options like the [duration](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#pan-options-duration) of the animation

here's an example:

```
my_map.flyToBounds(new L.polyline(LatLng).getBounds(), {'duration':0.25} )
```